# MySQL SELECT where IN (associative array[key]) AND SUM(Col5) IN >= (array[key2])

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sql-in

Let's say I have a table Colors with columns MainColor (Green, blue), Tone(44,17), Brand(Mybrand, Yourbrand, etc), Type(Standard, Special) and Availability
What I need is to display, according to a request like:

> Looking for **3x Green Tone 44**, **8x Green Tone 17** and **5x Blue Tone 44**

That stores in an array like this one:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [MainColor] => Green
            [Tone] => 44
            [Needed] => 3
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [MainColor] => Blue
            [Tone] => 44
            [Needed] => 5
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [MainColor] => Green
            [Tone] => 17
            [Needed] => 8
        )

)
```

Something like

> There are 3x Green Tone 44 (1x MyBrand Normal 1x Mybrand Special and 1x Yourbrand Standard)
>
> and 8x Green Tone 17 (1x Herbrand Special 2x Herbrand Standard, 4x Ourbrand Standard and 1x Hisbrand Special)
>
> and 5x Blue Tone 44 (3Mybrand Special and 2x Yourbrand Special)
>
> available color(s)

I know I can achieve the first 2 statements with something like:

```
SELECT *
    FROM Colors  
    WHERE MainColor IN (array['MainColor']) AND Tone IN (array['Tone'])
```

And what about the third one that needs to be summed and compared (greater than or equals the need amount)?

```
SELECT *
    FROM Colors  
    WHERE MainColor IN (array['MainColor']) AND Tone IN (array['Tone']) AND SUM(Colors.Availability) IN >= (array['Needed'])
```

Comment: Do you have any preferences as to how the brands are chosen?  If they can be all done from 1 brand, should it ignore the others or should it spread the quantity evenly?

Comment: what do you mean? I need to know the quantity by brand and type

Comment: In your example, you need 3 Green Tone 44, If every brand had (for example) 10 available, how would you decide which brands to use?

Comment: I would then print I have the 3x Green Tone 44 you need of the brands (brand1, brand2, brand3) types (special, standard) then display 3 rows (one for each color needed of green tone 44) with 2 selectbox, one for the brand and 1 for the type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you need to find all brands that have that particular colour/tone, so ignore the amounts, just list them if there are any available.

Then let the user select the quantity they want from each brand in a web page.  At this point you could enforce that the sum of the brands they select is as they have already entered (could do some JS to do this prior to submit) or could simply let them have as many or little as they want.

Only difficulty is if two people are offered the same colours/tones and they both try and order more stock than you have.  You will then have to check when they finally order them that the stock is still there.

Comment: I wanted to know if there was a query for effciently doing it directly in SQL, but I guess I'm going to go that way. Also what about the type?

Comment: The problem with doing it in SQL is that you don't know what brands or type they want.  That was why I wanted to understand how this was decided.  So as long as the Colour and Tone are available, list the brands and the types available ( using order by will allow you to group them for processing)

Comment: Right, I tought I could SUM up those columns I don't know yet the value